# C Python api ~ String Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault

I am new to the C Python api.
I know that there are alot of these questions, but I don't really understand them, since they are using different modules.
I started by creating a echo module, that will echo specific data types.
(echoINT(100), echoFLT(100.0), etc..)
I wish to add string support, although that is where the problems occur.
I can write a single, byte encoded char with this code:

```
//C character based echo
short /*<- An attempt to make the module a bit memory friendlier*/ CCHARecho(int CHAR) {
    return printf("%c\n", CHAR);
}

//Character based echo
static PyObject* echoCHAR(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    char CHAR;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "c", &CHAR))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    return Py_BuildValue("c", CCHARecho(CHAR));
}
//Python syntax: echoCHAR(b'A')
//Then just functions that build the module and all that.
```

But I get a segmentation fault with this code:

```
//C string based echo
int CSTRecho(char str[10000]) {
    return printf("%s", str);
}

static PyObject* echoStr(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    char str[10000];

    // PyArena_Malloc(str, sizeof(str));
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &str))
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return Py_BuildValue("s", CSTRecho(str));
}
```

I already slapped my code into gdb, and it turns out that the program tries to write to one specific memory location only.

```
(gdb) file python3
Reading symbols from python3...
(No debugging symbols found in python3)
(gdb) run test.py 
Starting program: /usr/bin/python3 test.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000054a850 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Here is the rest of the code to build the module:

```
static PyMethodDef echoMethod[] = {
    {"echoINT", echoINT, METH_VARARGS, "echo an integer."}, //"echo" = Python function, echo = points to C function, Take's arguments, Help menu
    {"echoCHAR", echoCHAR, METH_VARARGS, "echo a byte encoded char"},
    {"echoFLT", echoFLT, METH_VARARGS, "echo a floating point number"},
    {"Pecho", echoPOINTER, METH_VARARGS, "echo a memory address of a variable"},
    {"echoSTR", echoStr, METH_VARARGS, "echo a string"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL} //Terminate
};

static struct PyModuleDef echoModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "echoModule", //import echoModule
    "This is really just echo as seen in linux, but without variables.\n",
    -1, //Global
    echoMethod
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_echoModule(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&echoModule);
}
```

And finally, this is the code of the setup.py, which is ran with **python3 setup.py build**:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module = Extension('echoModule', sources = ['echoModule.c'])

setup (name = 'ECHO Package',
        version = '1.0',
        description = 'This is a package for echoModule.',
        ext_modules = [module])
```

Comment: Add `-g` to your compilation flags to include debug symbols, then gdb will be much more helpful. You can also give the command `bt` to get a backtrace.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but if im honest, I have no idea what I am supposed to see in back trace.
I mean I found the function that errors out, kind of. The function name is literally **?? ()**

Comment: Then the program probably crashed somewhere inside a Python API, but GDB doesn't have debuginfo for `libpython.so` -- see if you can install the debuginfo for Python for your distro.

Comment: Im on linux (debian).
For those who want to know the package that is needed, I used: **apt install gcc python3.8-dbg**